# Does mule restrict what spring namespaces are allowed to be used in the mule configuration file?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, spring-ldap

I am trying to use Spring LDAP inside of a Mule Application.  I have the following namespace config at the top of my mule configuration file:

```
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" 
xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit" 
xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" 
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" version="CE-3.5.0" 
xmlns:ldap="http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit/current/mule-apikit.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap.xsd">
```

And I have some beans and such configured as follows:

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="personRepoImpl" class="edu.ucdavis.iet.esb.directory.person.repo.ldap.PersonRepoImpl">
        <spring:property name="ldapTemplate" ref="ldapTemplate"/>
    </spring:bean>  
</spring:beans>

 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/ldap.properties" />

<ldap:context-source id="contextSource"
                     password="${sample.ldap.password}"
                     url="${sample.ldap.url}"
                     username="${sample.ldap.userDn}"
                     base="${sample.ldap.base}" />

<ldap:ldap-template id="ldapTemplate" context-source-ref="contextSource"/>
```

I keep getting a SAXParseException as follows:

```
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found
 starting with element 'ldap:ldap-template'. One of 
'{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/context":property-placeholder, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":ref,
 "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":global-property,
 "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":configuration,
 "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":notifications,
 "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-extension, 
"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-extension, 
"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-extension, 
"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-agent, 
"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-security-manager, 
"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transaction-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-transaction-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-connector, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-connector, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-exception-strategy,
 "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-flow-construct, 
"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":flow, 
"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":sub-flow, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-model, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-interceptor-stack, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-filter, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transformer, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":processor-chain, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":invoke, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-intercepting-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-queue-store, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-processing-strategy}' is expected.
```

So far as I can tell, I have the spring ldap config correct.  With this question, I want to rule out whether there are any namespace restrictions when defining other spring related projects in the Mule configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that there are no such limitations. However not all spring projects are bundled with the mule runtime.

Have you verified that the Spring ldap jars are available in your application class path. I don't think they are bundled with the Mule ESB Runtimes.

If they are, try to move the ldap:ldap-template element  inside the spring:beans element.